# Why appendAttributedString show appended string in a new line?

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

For example, I have 3 sentences such as @"Long long ago.",@"There is a child.",@"bla bla bla"
And I made a method below

```
- (void)appendText:(NSString*)text
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *originalText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:_textView.attributedText];
    NSAttributedString *appendText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                                                     attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:DefaultTextColor}];

    [originalText appendAttributedString:appendText];
    _textView.attributedText = originalText;
}
```

So I invoked appendText 3 times

```
[self appendText:@"Long long ago."];
[self appendText:@"There is a child."];
[self appendText:@"bla bla bla."];
```

The result I expected is

```
Long long ago.There is a child.bla bla bla.
```

But the output is

```
Long long ago.
There is a child.
bla bla bla
```

Why appendAttributedString show appended string in a new line? How can I put the appended text in one paragraph?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my own experiences, when you set the `attributedText` property of `UITextView`, the text is getting a newline added to it. So when you later retrieve the `attributedText` from the `UITextView`, this newline is at the end of the text. So when you append more text, the newline is in the middle (and another one is added to the end).

I don't know if this is a bug in `UITextView` or possibly `NSAttributedString`.

One workaround would be to update your code as follows:

```
- (void)appendText:(NSString*)text {
    NSMutableAttributedString *originalText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:_textView.attributedText];
    // Remove any trailing newline
    if (originalText.length) {
        NSAttributedString *last = [originalText attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(originalText.length - 1, 1)];
        if ([[last string] isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            originalText = [originalText attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, originalText.length - 1)];
        }
    }

    NSAttributedString *appendText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:DefaultTextColor}];

    [originalText appendAttributedString:appendText];
    _textView.attributedText = originalText;
}
```

Comment: It works like a charming. Thank you, rmaddy. You really saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleAttrString    = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
                                                 @"Hello" attributes:
                                                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  [UIFont  systemFontOfSize:15],NSFontAttributeName,
                                                  [UIColor blackColor], NSStrokeColorAttributeName,nil]];

NSAttributedString *descAttrString    = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
                                         @"\nWorld" attributes:
                                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont  systemFontOfSize:19],NSFontAttributeName,
                                          [UIColor blueColor], NSStrokeColorAttributeName,nil]];
[titleAttrString appendAttributedString:descAttrString];


NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]forKey: NSFontAttributeName];

CGSize tsize = [@"Test" boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-20, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                     options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;

UILabel *menuTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)-2, tsize.height+2)];
menuTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
menuTitle.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
menuTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
menuTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
menuTitle.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5f; // Chnage as your need
[GlobalSettings setCellLableProperities:menuTitle font:[GlobalSettings normalFont]];
menuTitle.font = [GlobalSettings getFontWith:9];
menuTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.11 blue:0.11 alpha:1.0];

menuTitle.attributedText = titleAttrString;
[self.view addSubview:menuTitle];
```